# Issue with param not pushing data to database in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form, strong-parameters

Quick one. I'm trying to push a parameter into the database when i'm creating an object. I have it working if I force the integer as with the commented code below however for whatever reason I cannot get it to be added to the database is I use the params[:subscription_id] method. I can see the parameters in my server but cannot see it getting inserted into the certificates table. If i force the integer in my controller it will go through and I can see the subscriptions_id getting passed in.

Does this have any reason to do with my relationship being a has_one relationship perhaps?

```
Certificate Controller

    class CertificatesController < ApplicationController
    def new 
        @certificate = Certificate.new
    end

    def create
        @certificate = Certificate.new(certificate_params)
        @certificate.subscription_id = params[:subscription_id]
        #@certificate.subscription_id = 1


        if @certificate.save
            flash[:success] = "The certificate has been uploaded"
            redirect_to :back
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    private

  def certificate_params
    params.require(:certificate).permit(:document, :title, :subscription_id)
  end

end
```

View code:

```
<%= link_to "upload certificate", new_certificate_path(subscription_id: subscription.id) %>
```

Models

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :course
    has_one :certificate
end


class Certificate < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :subscription

    has_attached_file :document
    #validates_attachment :document, content_type: %w(application/pdf application/msword application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document)
    do_not_validate_attachment_file_type :document
end
```

Certificate Form

```
  <div class="row">
        <div class="site-forms">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                <%= simple_form_for @certificate do |f| %>
                        <!-- <= f.input :course_img, as: :file, required: true, label: "Please upload a brand image for your course" %><br> -->
                        <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                            <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload fa-lg"></i> Upload Image
                            <%= f.input :document, as: :file, required: true, label: false %>
                        </span>  Please upload Certificate as PDF <br><br>
                    <%= f.input :title, placeholder: "Course Title", required: true, label: "Course Title" %>
                    <%= f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
                    <% end %>
                </div>
        </div>
  </div>
```

This is probably something stupid i'm missing but I can get it to work if I force the integer in the commented out code in the controller. I'm nearly sure the params code is correct. Thanks.

Added logs

```
    Started POST "/certificates" for ::1 at 2017-05-23 20:40:30 +0100
Processing by CertificatesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"6fV0xLOoy6ppNG7PYp37vkKqJnxU17nLPSK/mvbgH8k3s2LyaMEOJlekq5S0Ed4fpbNcqVe+cBsu5F38ACCmcg==", "certificate"=>{"document"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f954362c160 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/gx/86yj74bx3md88cfn2fwc975h0000gn/T/RackMultipart20170523-5261-1n2mwfl.png>, @original_filename="duck.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"certificate[document]\"; filename=\"duck.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">, "title"=>"Test"}, "commit"=>"Create Certificate"}
Command :: PATH=/usr/local/bin/:$PATH; file -b --mime '/var/folders/gx/86yj74bx3md88cfn2fwc975h0000gn/T/36846677e3a8f4c0b16d8bdf8ef1860820170523-5261-e90bny.png'
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
Command :: PATH=/usr/local/bin/:$PATH; file -b --mime '/var/folders/gx/86yj74bx3md88cfn2fwc975h0000gn/T/36846677e3a8f4c0b16d8bdf8ef1860820170523-5261-1d907er.png'
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "certificates" ("document_file_name", "document_content_type", "document_file_size", "document_updated_at", "title", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["document_file_name", "duck.png"], ["document_content_type", "image/png"], ["document_file_size", 49114], ["document_updated_at", "2017-05-23 19:40:30.662715"], ["title", "Test"], ["created_at", "2017-05-23 19:40:30.683041"], ["updated_at", "2017-05-23 19:40:30.683041"]]
   (0.7ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/certificates/new?subscription_id=3
Completed 302 Found in 36ms (ActiveRecord: 1.1ms)


Started GET "/certificates/new?subscription_id=3" for ::1 at 2017-05-23 20:40:30 +0100
Processing by CertificatesController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"subscription_id"=>"3"}
  Rendered certificates/_form.html.erb (7.7ms)
  Rendered certificates/new.html.erb within layouts/application (8.7ms)
  Rendered shared/_message.html.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 95ms (Views: 94.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: Don't have time to dive into it right now, will look more later. But my gut immediately goes to "accepts nested attributes for" in this situation. That way the Certificates controller can set the attribute represented by `@certificate.subscription_id`. Also, is the corresponding Subscription already existing? Or does it need the `.build` command?

Comment: Also please post your web server console output when you try to save. That way we can see the actual `params[]` that are being passed to the controller. It is probable that your value is `nil` so that is what is being passed unless you explicitly call `=1` in your controller.

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#building-complex-forms

Comment: Tried the accept_nested_attributes in my certificate model to allow subscription. Still nothing. The subscription is already built previously and I'm adding a certificate to subscriptions once the course is finished. Everything else works fine except adding the subscription_id and i'm doing this via parameters.

Comment: Look at your logs: You create the new Cert, but in the params there is no `subscription_id`. So `params[:subscription_id]` is nil. Where is `susbscription_id` in your form? See your params hash being returned with the form, is there a `subscription_id: 3` anywhere that I am missing? You need to set that somewhere before you submit the form. How can the controller know the context of WHICH subscription it's dealing with if you never tell it?

Comment: Thank you Beartech. Got it. So removed the controller code that added the subscription_id and included a hidden tag into the form that pulled the parameter. 

<%= f.hidden_field :subscription_id, :value => params[:subscription_id] %>

Not sure why I though was able to just use the controller to pull the param. Would I be right in saying when the form is sent and the controller creates the object that the param is obviously blank then and so brings in a nil or well doesn't include it at all in the log.

Comment: Makes sense having the hidden field in the form now. I'm nearly sure I have something very similar in my app that works the same way i've tried that's been failing on this one. 

Anyways. Either way it's working now. Legend. How do I accept this as an answer if it is just a comment? Thanks again.

Comment: I think if were using a route like `/subscription/3/certificate` it would be more "automatic" like you were expecting.

Comment: Added it as an answer if you want to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set your `subscription_id` in a hidden field so that it gets passed in the params hash.

```
<%= f.hidden_field :subscription_id, :value => params[:subscription_id] %>
```

That way it gets set with the rest of the params.

Comment: Thanks again Beartech, was as simple as this. I over looked the form by trying to add the parameter in the controller.

Answer (score 1):

Params are strings. Try

```
@certificate.subscription_id = params[:subscription_id].to_i
```

Comment: Hmm didn't even cop that params are a string. Ok so add the to_i method and it feeds in a subscription_id. Only error now is that the subscription_id is feeding in as 0. I've looked at the server and it's showing the parameter correct when the GET method grabs it from the parameter however when being inserted into the table it shows it to be 0.

Comment: params[:subscription_id] = "1" ?

Comment: No I meant if I force at.certificate.subscription_id = 1 in my controller I can get the subscription_id to feed into the db. 

If I put at.certificate.subscription_id = params[:subscription_id]
It doesn't get recognised when Inserting into database. 

So I know the code is working until I pull the params from the url. http://localhost:3000/certificates/new?subscription_id=3

Comment: on this url, localhost:3000/certificates/new?subscription_id=3, if you log params, it shows the subscription id = 0?

Comment: Hi Margo, no if I change the parameters to_i it'll feed in a 0. Otherwise it's null and I can see it in the logs not being included into the table even though I can see the parameter value being correct. It just wont put the parameter into the table. Does the relationship set up have any say in this method?

Answer (score 0):

Try change this function as below

```
  def certificate_params
     params.require(:certificate).permit(:document, :title, :subscription_id, :subscription)
  end
```

Maybe allow permit subscription field from params.

Comment: Permitting the subscription doesn't work. No idea why it is not pulling in the parameter values. This is the log.

Comment: Seems like you missed your subscription_id pass into create action. Use hidden field.